# Using mlxtend's StackingClassifier with Keras Classifier neural net

Tags: python, keras, classification

I've used mlxtend's stacking classifier with success on most of sklearn's classifiers, but I can't seem to get it to work when I use a keras classifier sklearn wrapper.  I think it has to do with the way the data is transformed for the neural net (using the values attribute of the dataset), but I can't figure out how to change the data so that it can be used in the keras classifier and in the stacking classifier.

Here is my code:

```
nn_data = training_data.values
nn = prediction_data.drop(['id', 'era', 'data_type'], axis=1)
nn_prediction = nn.values
x = nn_data[:,3:53]
y = nn_data[:,53]
clf1 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=nn_model, epochs=9, batch_size=2000, verbose=2)
lr = LR.LogisticRegression()
sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1], meta_classifier=lr, use_probas=True)
sclf.fit(x, y)
```

and here is my error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cb767df93cc9> in <module>()
      4 mlp = MLPClassifier()
      5 sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1], meta_classifier=lr, use_probas=True)
----> 6 sclf.fit(x, y)
      7 y_prediction_sclf = sclf.predict_proba(x_pred)
      8 print ('final_model logloss = ' + str(metrics.log_loss(y_pred, y_prediction_sclf)))

/Users/wahabkazi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlxtend/classifier/stacking_classification.py in fit(self, X, y)
    118 
    119         if not self.use_features_in_secondary:
--> 120             self.meta_clf_.fit(meta_features, y)
    121         else:
    122             self.meta_clf_.fit(np.hstack((X, meta_features)), y)

/Users/wahabkazi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1215         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype,
   1216                          order="C")
-> 1217         check_classification_targets(y)
   1218         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
   1219         n_samples, n_features = X.shape

/Users/wahabkazi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 172         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    173 
    174 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

Here is a sample value of x:
array([0.49282, 0.58077, 0.48948, 0.56762, 0.56107, 0.51168,
       0.47458999999999996, 0.56968, 0.47402, 0.40326, 0.54119,
       0.5319699999999999, 0.31899, 0.43153, 0.35538000000000003,
       0.6613100000000001, 0.42477, 0.65484, 0.49437, 0.6126699999999999,
       0.60285, 0.38813000000000003, 0.49818999999999997, 0.59332, 0.63041,
       0.40815, 0.47767, 0.4869, 0.51394, 0.5371600000000001,
       0.49223999999999996, 0.44978, 0.49446999999999997,
       0.46531999999999996, 0.51057, 0.52177, 0.54243, 0.61623, 0.56988,
       0.66293, 0.50138, 0.40333, 0.52337, 0.60795, 0.35748, 0.49677,
       0.28295, 0.65342, 0.57915, 0.51136], dtype=object)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please add some samples of your data, especially `y`. What type of problem is this:- binary, multiclass, etc?

Comment: this is a binary classification problem.  I posted a sample point from x in the original post.  y is just a target value (0 or 1).

Comment: You should post the output of `print(y)`. Is the dtype of `y` object or int?

Comment: it's an int:
print(y)
[ 1.  1.  0. ...,  1.  1.  1.]